# Warnings when using graph queries in Visual Studio Database Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, graph-table

We have some SQL "normal" and graph tables, a script that syncs the information between them.

Everything is working ok from SSMS but when building the database project in Visual Studio using msbuild we get warnings (see code and warnings details below).

If we set `TreatTSqlWarningsAsErrors` to True these warnings become errors.

We don't want to ignore warnings but its unclear why we even get them.
Are these warnings correct?

Why are they showing in Visual Studio only and not in SSMS?

How can we resolve them without ignoring them?

The details:

We have the following two "normal" SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Currency]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [UId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Currency] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Currency] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Currency_UId] DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [UId]
GO
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Portfolio]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](250) NULL,
    [CurrencyId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [UId] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_Portfolio] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                           ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Portfolio] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Portfolio_UId] DEFAULT (NEWID()) FOR [UId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Portfolio] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Portfolio_Currency] 
        FOREIGN KEY([CurrencyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Currency] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Portfolio] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Portfolio_Currency]
GO
```

and we created the following SQL graph schema together with two SQL node tables and one SQL edge:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [graph] ;

CREATE TABLE [graph].[Currency] 
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    INDEX [GRAPH_UNIQUE_INDEX_4FFC60C0FCBE4843A7F4B9AB0729FF78] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ($node_id)
) AS NODE;


CREATE TABLE [graph].[Portfolio] 
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    INDEX [GRAPH_UNIQUE_INDEX_F39F92BE8DD34DD791D6CA955DA0DA9A] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ($node_id)
) AS NODE;

CREATE TABLE [graph].[isOf] 
(
    [IsActive] BIT CONSTRAINT [DF_isOf_IsActive] DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    INDEX [GRAPH_UNIQUE_INDEX_AD8C5B40D277413580EDD943AC192869] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ($edge_id)
) AS EDGE;

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UQ_FromTo]
    ON [graph].[isOf] ($from_id, $to_id) ON [PRIMARY];
GO
```

A sync stored procedure which will populate the nodes and the edge from the "normal" tables that will be executed daily.

Attached parts of it:

```
PRINT ( 'Sync graph.[Portfolio]' );
INSERT INTO graph.Portfolio ( Id )
            SELECT P.[UId]
            FROM   dbo.Portfolio P
            WHERE  NOT EXISTS (   SELECT 1
                                  FROM   graph.Portfolio G
                                  WHERE  G.Id = P.[UId] );

PRINT ( 'Sync graph.[Currency]' );
INSERT INTO graph.Currency ( Id )
            SELECT C.[UId]
            FROM   dbo.Currency C
            WHERE  NOT EXISTS (   SELECT 1
                                  FROM   graph.Currency G
                                  WHERE  G.Id = C.[UId] );


PRINT('Sync Portfolio isOf Currency edge');
;
WITH UidCTE
AS ( SELECT P.[UId] AS PortfolioUid ,
            C.[UId] AS CurrencyUid
    FROM   dbo.Portfolio P
            JOIN dbo.Currency C ON C.Id = P.CurrencyId )
MERGE graph.isOf AS TGT
USING graph.[Portfolio] AS SourceFrom
JOIN UidCTE CTE ON SourceFrom.Id = CTE.PortfolioUid
JOIN graph.[Currency] AS SourceTo ON CTE.CurrencyUid = SourceTo.Id
ON MATCH(SourceFrom-(TGT)->SourceTo)
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
                INSERT ( $from_id , $to_id )
                VALUES ( SourceFrom.$node_id, SourceTo.$node_id)
        WHEN MATCHED AND TGT.[IsActive] = 0 THEN 
            UPDATE SET TGT.[IsActive] = 1;
```

and the following script which updates the edge's IsActive column in case the relationship doesn't exist anymore in the "normal" tables(we don't want to delete it from the graph nodes/edges)

```
;WITH PortfolioIsOfCurrency
AS ( SELECT P.[UId] AS PortfolioUid ,
            C.[UId] AS CurrencyUid
     FROM   dbo.Portfolio P
            JOIN dbo.Currency C ON C.Id = P.CurrencyId ) ,
      NodeCTE
AS ( SELECT P.$node_id AS FromNode ,
            C.$node_id AS ToNode
     FROM   PortfolioIsOfCurrency CTE
            JOIN graph.Portfolio P ON P.Id = CTE.PortfolioUid
            JOIN graph.Currency C ON C.Id = CTE.CurrencyUid )
UPDATE ISOF
SET    isOf.IsActive = 0
FROM   graph.isOf ISOF
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (   SELECT 1
                      FROM   NodeCTE N
                      WHERE  N.FromNode = ISOF.$from_id
                             AND N.ToNode = ISOF.$to_id );
```

We created a database project in VS 2019 with the following settings:

```
<DSP>Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql150DatabaseSchemaProvider</DSP>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TreatWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
<TreatTSqlWarningsAsErrors>False</TreatTSqlWarningsAsErrors>
```

From SSMS everything works perfect.

The problem is with the last syntax(UPDATE isof.active) I get the following warnings:

> Warning SQL71502: Procedure: [graph].[SyncEngagementContentGraphs] has an unresolved reference to object [graph].[isOf].[N].  graph\Stored Procedures\SyncEngagementContentGraphs.sql 57
>
> Warning SQL71502: Procedure: [graph].[SyncEngagementContentGraphs] has an unresolved reference to object [graph].[isOf].[N].  graph\Stored Procedures\SyncEngagementContentGraphs.sql 58
>
> Warning SQL71509: The model already has an element that has the same name NodeCTE.$node_id.       graph\Stored Procedures\SyncEngagementContentGraphs.sql 47
>
> Warning SQL71509: The model already has an element that has the same name NodeCTE.$node_id.       graph\Stored Procedures\SyncEngagementContentGraphs.sql 48

and if we set TreatTSqlWarningsAsErrors to True these warnings become errors and we cannot leave it like this (set to False) in the long run.

Comment: `SyncEngagementContentGraphs.sql` Could you mark the lines 47,48,57,58 in your code?

Comment: I would remove the alias `UPDATE ISOF
SET    isOf.IsActive = 0` => `UPDATE ISOF
SET    IsActive = 0`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Many thanks for helping. 
Here are the lines:
47:  AS ( SELECT P.$node_id AS FromNode ,

48:     C.$node_id AS ToNode

57:                  WHERE  N.FromNode = ISOF.$from_id

58:          AND N.ToNode = ISOF.$to_id );

Comment: @LukaszSzozda tested the update without an Alias, same problem. I think it is related to $node_id (alias) usage from the node tables.
  
  UPDATE graph.isOf
  SET    IsActive = 0
  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (   SELECT 1
         FROM   NodeCTE N
         WHERE  N.FromNode = graph.isOf.$from_id
          AND N.ToNode = graph.isOf.$to_id );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to define correctly the NodeCTE common table expression with columns names.

This seems to be mandatory in the case of a CTE with graph tables.

The correct query whithout warnings would be:

```
;WITH PortfolioIsOfCurrency
AS ( SELECT P.[UId] AS PortfolioUid ,
            C.[UId] AS CurrencyUid
     FROM   dbo.Portfolio P
            JOIN dbo.Currency C ON C.Id = P.CurrencyId ) ,
      **NodeCTE(FromNode, ToNode)**
AS ( SELECT P.$node_id AS FromNode ,
            C.$node_id AS ToNode
     FROM   PortfolioIsOfCurrency CTE
            JOIN graph.Portfolio P ON P.Id = CTE.PortfolioUid
            JOIN graph.Currency C ON C.Id = CTE.CurrencyUid )
UPDATE ISOF
SET    isOf.IsActive = 0
FROM   graph.isOf ISOF
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (   SELECT 1
                      FROM   NodeCTE N
                      WHERE  N.FromNode = ISOF.$from_id
                             AND N.ToNode = ISOF.$to_id );
```

This change is needed just for the VS SqlProject warnings. Both versions work with no problems with SSMS/ADS.